# simple search of text from table without effecting laravel pagenation

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a simple table which have alist of jobs. here i have a input type of text to enter the text to search .when i enter any text in search input it gives me the findings. but the problem is i'm using laravel pageination. when the serach on keyup function it gives the finding of page1 table and page2 table etc.here i need the whole finding of table tr's where the text is matching.Below i'm adding my code.
        but remainging pages results are not showing there.the whole result of that text contains 6 's but it shows only two from page1.I need the whole result of 6 .Here i used a simple search from table i dont need any findings from db.I'mincuding a simple search of text from table.

```
    $('#search').on('keyup', function(e) {
        if ('' != this.value) {
            var reg = new RegExp(this.value, 'i'); // case-insesitive

            $('.table tbody').find('tr').each(function() {
                var $me = $(this);
                if (!$me.children('td').text().match(reg)) {
                    $me.hide();
                } else {
                    $me.show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('.table tbody').find('tr').show();
        }
    });
```

[it is the page1 serach result shows two data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEp7Y.png)

Comment: you just filter the first page result, you would have to send the searchword to laravel and actually search in the database and return appropriate result-pages

Comment: or you can use datatable jquery plugin and use laravel datatable for the backend

Answer (score 0):

You can try Laravel DataTable library and use server side pagination, you can search and filter your entire table.

[Laravel DataTable](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master)